# LemonWay MoneyIn3DInit response 262

Tags: php, codeigniter, payment

I have just started to use Lemonway and i want to test my payments on my machine with the function MoneyIn3DInit but i can't get more informations on why i get this error code :

```
object(LemonWay\ApiResponse)[37]
  public 'lwXml' => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[39]
      public 'E' => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[41]
          public 'Error' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[45]
              ...
          public 'Code' => string '262' (length=3)
          public 'Msg' => string 'Payment account is not valid' (length=38)
          public 'Prio' => string '2' (length=1)
  public 'lwError' => 
    object(LemonWay\Models\LwError)[40]
      public 'CODE' => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[43]
          public 0 => string '262' (length=3)
      public 'MSG' => string 'Payment account is not valid ()' (length=41)
  public 'wallet' => null
  public 'wallets' => null
  public 'operations' => null
  public 'operation' => null
  public 'kycDoc' => null
  public 'iban' => null
  public 'sddMandate' => null
  public 'acs' => null
  public 'vcc' => null
  public 'card' => null
  public 'ideal' => null
```

If anyone has an idea, it will be greatly apreciated.

Comment: Is this not the error `Le compte de paiement n'est pas valide`

Comment: The error message translates to _"The payment account is not valid"_ (Google translate) so I would start there.

Comment: I checked the doc here : 
http://documentation.lemonway.fr/api-en/annex/error-codes-of-our-directkit
but I can't have more information

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't know how much help we can be, if the message from the server is that the payment account is invalid.